# Post BASE64 to server

Tags: java, android, post, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send one image with BASE64 to server and always got 408 with this message "The request body did not contain the specified number of bytes. Got 13.140, expected 88.461". How can I solve that?

I tried to use Retrofit, HttpURLConnection and got the same error. I think that is some parameter on app.

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String jsonParam = gson.toJson(enviarPlataforma);

                    URL url = new URL("");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(jsonParam.getBytes().length);


                    Log.i("JSON", jsonParam.toString());
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    os.writeBytes(jsonParam);

                    os.flush();
                    os.close();

                    Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                    Log.i("MSG", conn.getResponseMessage());

                    conn.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: When you use `os.writeBytes(String);` it discards high end byte. Instead use `os.writeBytes(jsonParam.getBytes(), 0, jsonParam.getBytes().length);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UTF-8 bytes must be taken, and send as-is. The DataOutputStream is for something else entirely. As it is one write, you can simply use the OutputStream you get from the connection. A BufferedOutputStream probably serves no purpose.

Flushing before a close is never needed. One needs to flush on a standing, continuing line only.

Try-with-resources closes automatically, also when some exception was thrown.

```
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                //conn.setDoInput(true);

                byte[] content = jsonParam.getBytes("UTF-8"):
                conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(content.length);

                Log.i("JSON", jsonParam.toString());
                try (OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
                    os.write(content);
                }
```

Comment: It's not this :/

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem. I don't know why but when I'm using Fiddler I got this message.

Thank you guys.